# Winform application throwing an error for a database table with name as 'Program'

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6, desktop-application

I am using EntityFrameowrk6 in my winforms desktop application. In the database, there is a table named 'Program'. Under my .edmx file, there is a class with the name Program generated for Program database table. The application throws an error saying that:

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Program
{

}
```

Comment: You can't have a `Program` class, there is already one that is created automatically. If you want (or need) to have one, you need to modify your program's entry class, also called `Program` and name it something else, then modify the build settings to point to that new class.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I don't think if I am creating a windows forms application that Program class is created automatically. I don't see that class in my solution explorer. The program class got added when I imported the database table 'Program' through entityframeowork

Comment: @GertArnold, the Program class is under .edmx file generated through EntityFramework. I don't have another Pogram class in my solution

Comment: @GertArnold: Namespaces are the key. If you put it in a separate class library with the same namespace, you're still in a bit of trouble.

Comment: @GertArnold: When you start using the a class `Program` in your application you reference the EF library from, the trouble begins. When they are in the same NS, there still is a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there was a class named `Program` before in your project, which you had to delete when EF6 added its own `Program` class to avoid a compiler error. Alas, the `Program` class in the default console application, WinForms and WPF project contains a static method called `Main`. Every application needs such a method as an entry point and yours is gone now. You can do either of the following:

1. Put the project's `Program` class and the EF `Program` class in different namespaces, then you can have both of them. While you're at it, consider putting your EF classes in a separate class library, which you can reference from your application.
2. Add your static `Main` method in a different class. It doesn't need to be in a class called `Program`.

Comment: EF added program class becuase the database I am using had a table with the name "Program"

Comment: @jay: I am aware of that. That still conflicts with your existing `Program` class if you don't choose the namespace of your autogenerated classes to avoid the conflict.